# Best way to make a login with Ruby on Rails, using webservices to validate a username and password

Tags: web-services, ruby-on-rails-3, soap, authentication

I need a hint on which is the best way to make a good login on Ruby on Rails, using webservices with SOAP protocol to validate the user and password.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that you would like to either use a standard user and password system and, in addition, log the user in through external APIs (like Facebook Connect or Twitter API), I'd definitely use [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) with OAuth. There's plenty of tutorials to do this, for example [with facebook](http://www.stjhimy.com/posts/14-allowing-devise-login-with-facebook-account), and there are even specific gems, for example [for Twitter](https://github.com/MSch/devise-twitter) and [for Facebook](https://github.com/grimen/devise_facebook_connectable). Another way could be to use devise with [Janrain](https://rpxnow.com/) (formerly known as RPXnow), which provides an unique interface for a lot of web services (among which again Facebook and Twitter, but also Google, Yahoo!, Flickr, AOL, etc.). And of course there's a [gem](https://github.com/slainer68/devise_rpx_connectable) to integrate devise with RPX.

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't know too much about these things yet... Can you use OAuth asking an own module (i already made a module that can validate a user)